# How to get a detailed error message in Capybara unit tests

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

How do I get a detailed error message in Capybara unit tests?

```
describe "About" do
it "should have the h1 'About Us'" do
  visit '/static_pages/about'
  page.should have_selector('h1', 
    :text => "About Us")
end
it "should have the title 'About'" do
  visit '/static_pages/about'
page.should have_title("About")
end
```

This tests for title to be "About".

How do I add a custom error message like:

```
Expected "About" but found "ABT". Please Rectify the mistake.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a custom error message described in "[Customized message](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/customized-message)" like this:

```
it "should have the title 'About'" do
  visit '/static_pages/about'
  expect(page).to have_title("About"), lambda { "Expected 'About' but found '#{page.first("title", visible: false).native.text}'. Please Rectify the mistake."}
end
```

Comment: Due to Capybaras waiting behavior you probably want the custom message to be a proc so it gets evaluated after the failure rather than before the search begins.

Comment: Excellent suggestion @TomWalpole. I updated my answer with a lambda.

Comment: It shows error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Comment: Does anyone know how to add to the default message rather than replace it?

Comment: I would like to note, this will not work for finding ids on the page, the only way I have seen to work through that with that matcher is to use a rescue block

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom error messages as shown below, also you should add to take screenshot to debug the issue.

```
describe "About" do
it "should have the h1 'About Us'" do
  visit '/static_pages/about'
  page.should have_selector('h1', 
    :text => "About Us")
end
it "should have the title 'About'" do
  visit '/static_pages/about'
  textToSearch="About"
  begin
    page.should have_title("#{textToSearch}")
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Expected '#{textToSearch}' but found '#{page.first("title", visible: false).native.text}'. Please Rectify the mistake."
    randomNumber=rand(100000)
    page.save_screenshot("abc-#{randomNumber}.png",:full=>true)
    raise e
  end
end
```

Hope this will Helps :)